# IIS7.5 URL Rewrite, how can I get the proper callbacks?

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to write a regex that matches the {QUERY_STRING} condition type.

**Sample Data:**

```
slug=something1 &slug=something2 &slug=something3 &slug=something4 &id=5645
```

*Note: I've added the spaces for easier reading.*

**Regex so far:**

```
^(slug=(\w+)|&slug=(\w+)|&id=(\d+))+
```

With this I'm able to access 5 callbacks:

- {C:0} slug=something1 &slug=something2 &slug=something3
  &slug=something4 &id=5645
- {C:1} &id=5645
- {C:2} *empty*
- {C:3} *empty*
- {C:4} 5645

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

- {C:0} slug=something1 &slug=something2 &slug=something3
  &slug=something4 &id=5645
- {C:1} something1
- {C:2} something2
- {C:3} something3
- {C:4} something4
- {C:5} 5645

**One other requirement:**

I'm always passing the **id** as the last variable, and I'd like it to be in the 5th position all the time regardless of how many slugs are passed (to a maximum of 4, minimum of 1).  Is this even possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(?:slug=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&)?(?:slug=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&)?(?:slug=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&)?(?:slug=([a-zA-Z0-9]+))?id=(\d+)+
```

Repeating the pattern is somewhat ugly, but I'm just not smart enough to find another expression.

The ?: in

```
(?:slug=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)&)
```

tells the processor not to capture the match.

This also achieves what you were asking for: the ID is always in C:5.

I tried this in my IIS 7.5 and it works, *except* if there is just one slug - in that case, this slug is captured into C:3. I have no idea why. Other regex testers (like http://regex101.com/#pcre) capture correctly.

I'll think about it, but if this takes too long or I don't come up with a solution, you can always add multiple rewrite rules (in this case, add an extra rule for **one** slug).

This is how it looks in IIS:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, this works on the ID, but I also need all of the slug information which it doesn't seem to be getting.  ID really is the most important part here and it is ALL that I need... but how do I rewrite the URL with the slug info if I can't pull it from the captured conditions?

Comment: Can you try again? Because I really got ALL the information exactly as required. I added an image to clarify where I put what in the URL Rewrite module.

Comment: Ahh, yes I see.  It is working, thank you. I still have this bug that you've mentioned where the it improperly captures into the wrong callback position... I also can't figure out why.  I've added an adjustment to account for dashes and underscores as well to the regex `(?:slug=([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)&)` - I'll keep working at it. Thanks for putting me on the right path.